# Call JavaScript function on a dynamically created delete asp.button code behind when every time a user clicks on delete

Tags: javascript, vb.net

I couldn't post my code because I had an error message from Stackover flow that my code is not indented even though I did that. Anyways, a general example should do the job. Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the validation error had a reason ...

Comment: Hey @JonasW. I understand you're trying to close this request out; however, did you try to look at it from a different point of view. For example, I might be new and might be learning on how to use StackOverflow, but currently I need help because my project is difficult? If you think you can't help, at least let others respond to my question. I am in a bind whereby I need help from other developers who are better than myself. Much Appreciation

Comment: If you want help, post your code! These are not my rules, those are the rules of the comunity

Comment: Sure will do, Thanks a lot. @JonasW.